# Displaying multiple match values list in excel column drop down

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My Excel Sheet2 have below data.

| Vendor_id | Vendor_Name | Vendor_Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KN123 | Kinley | Chennai |
| KN123 | Kinley | Bangalore |
| TATA523 | TATA | Mumbai |
| TATA523 | TATA | Hyderabad |

Query : In sheet 1 when i select the Vendor_ID from drop down i need to display the corresponding vendor locations in the vendor_location drop down column.

( For example when i select KN123  i need to display Chennai, Bangalore in vendor_location column drop down.)

I used the XLOOKUP to achieve this, but i am getting the only one value.

=XLOOKUP(E5,Data!A:A,Data!$D:$D)

i placed the above function in data validation list source.

when i select KN123 i am getting only first value in the Vendor_Location drop down(Chennai).

Please help me to include all the matching locations in the drop down.

Comment: You have to use a helper column to achieve this. Please note `XLOOKUP()` is not available on `Excel-2010`. So, remove tag `Excel-2010`.

Comment: Oops - I did not see the Excel-2010 - my solution is a no go in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Excel 2019 or Excel 365, you can do:

```
=FILTER( Data!$D:$D, Data!A:A = E5)
```

Comment: Hi Mardk,  Could you please let me know the use of = E5 .

Comment: I was just re-interpreting your XLOOKUP into the FILTER function. You wrote `=XLOOKUP(E5,Data!A:A,Data!$D:$D)`, so I used E5, Data!A:A, Data!$D:$D in the same way as you, but placed into FILTER to deliver a Dynamic Array with all locations for the Company matching E5.

Comment: I suspect that you have mixed up the company column with the address column.  In your XLOOKUP, you were comparing E5 to column Data!A:A.  In the function that you just posted above `=FILTER(Data!A:A,Data!B:B = Sheet1!E5)` you are comparing it to Data!B:B. Here is what youre FILTER function should do: FILTER( address column, company column = target company ID ).  So, perhaps you need to change your formula to =FILTER(Data!B:B,Data!A:A = Sheet1!E5).

Comment: Hi Mark, when i use the =FILTER( Data!$D:$D, Data!A:A = E5) in data validation list source i am getting "the source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?" message.  if i select Yes, i am not getting the values in the drop down.  If i use the same function in excel sheet cell i am getting the values. but i need to show that values as drop down list.

Comment: Ahh OK - there are certain functions that cannot be placed in a Data Validation dropdown: SORT, UNIQUE and unfortunately FILTER.  You would have to use a helper cell range to make this work - i.e. put the FILTER function in a cell and then set your dropdown cell range equal to the range.  I think there could be a way to do this with INDEX, but cannot recall how it is done. :-(